# probability of equiprobable events

Tags: probability

suppose we have set of equiprobable events as follow:
{∅,a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,abc,abd,acd,bcd,abcd} 
whereas a b c and d are four different features that might be observed solely or coupled with each others as per in the set above. 
the set above has resulted by setting all possible combination between these two features (number of combinations is equal to 2 exponent  to n ; whereas  n is number of features) so when for example {a} appear in any combination that will increase the probability weight of {a} (in this example Pr(a) = 8/16 and so on)

how can we calculate the probability of

1- P(a) ?

2- P(ab) ?

3- P(a∣b) ?

is there any optimised way to find these probabilities without writing the all outcomes and just count ( imagine if n was 12 … the problem space will be 2^12 !!! ) i tried to use hypergeometric pmf to work it out but i couldn’t do it !!!

Comment: The events are independent?  But then just count.  Hint:  the possible outcomes can be thought of as a string of $1$'s and $0$'s according to whether the isolated event attached to a given slot occurs or does not occur.

Comment: which it is. but i really am not able to automate the calculation without writing down all possible outcomes. 
the occurrence of an event is independent of the others. when i said Pr(a|b) i mean what is the probability of having a given that we already observed b which equals 4/8

Comment: thank you. i meant a occurs along with possible some others 
what about ab ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Any event that is equiprobable with ∅ has probability zero.

Comment: @ana Assuming that you have n independent events, each occurring with the same probability, then the usual rules of probability apply, and the probability that two of them both occur is just the product.  As they are independent, knowing that one occurred (or didn't) conveys no information about the other.

Comment: ∅ is the event when we didn’t select any of the features a,b,c or d

Comment: @ByronSchmuland  I believe the OP means that the "core events" {a,b,c,d} are equiprobable.  Moreover, I believe they are all meant to have probability $\frac 12$.  I agree that this is not clear from what is written.

Comment: thank you all . this had open up a little bit for me :) highly appreciative

Answer (score 1):

Using the notation $2^X$ to denote the set of all subsets of the set $X$, we have
$$
P(a) = \frac{|2^{\{b,c,d\}}|}{|2^{\{a,b,c,d\}}|} = \frac{2^3}{2^4}=\frac 1 2
$$
since the event '$a$' is actually the set of all subsets $E \subset {\{a,b,c,d\}}$ such that $a \in E$, which is in bijection with $2^{\{b,c,d\}}$.

Similarly,
$$
P(ab) = \frac{|2^{\{c,d\}}|}{|2^{\{a,b,c,d\}}|} = \frac{2^2}{2^4} = \frac 1 {2^2}
$$
Finally,
$$
P(a \mid b) = \frac{P(ab)}{P(b)} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. that was really helpful for me :)

Comment: @ana: You're welcome. Since you are new, let me warn you that 'thank you' comments are discouraged on this website. But don't forget to upvote the answers you find useful and eventually accept the best answer.

Comment: i really didn’t know that. but i will definitely vote